# Rate of change of the slope of the tangent

Tags: derivatives

I have this question:
Find the rate of change of the slope of the tangent of the function $f(x)=-x^3$ at $x=8$

there are two solutions and i can't decide which is correct.

1- I'll find the second derivative and then substitute by $x=8$ so the answer will be $-48$

2- I'll find the slope (first derivative) and then substitute by $x=8$, and then find second derivative which will be zero.

which one is correct and why?!

Comment: Find 2nd derivative and then substitute .

Comment: Why? this is the main question? @AmruthA

Comment: you want to find slope of slope @ a point ,so find the equation of slope of slope i.e 2nd derivative , then substitute the point in the eqn.

Comment: The 2nd is obviously wrong. It would give the answer 0 in all cases irrespective of the function $f(x)$!

Answer (score 1):

The second solution is wrong, because it amounts to replacing a function ($y'(x)$) with its value at a point, thus turning a function to a constant function. This way, you get that the derivative of *any* function is $0$!

Answer (score 0):

The second one is wrong.

Reason: you are finding $f'(x)=-3x^2$ and so $f'(8)=-192$.  You are then differentiating again

- **but** -

you are assuming that $f'(x)$ is always equal to $-192$, whereas in fact this is only true when $x=8$.

Comment: Sorry, i don't get it, can you further explain?

Answer (score 0):

First derivative is only in transit, leave it off because its purpose has been served already to get to the next, second derivative.

So straightaway plug in $ x=8$ in the *second* derivative.